# How to turn classification tree results into a GIS map

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, image-classification

I'm new-ish to machine learning, so this could be a silly question. Apologies if so.

The idea is is to predict groundwater occurrence based on a regression tree. 
This is my conceptual model:

- Target variable: well success rate (the spatial location of those wells that did/didn't find groundwater). This is spatially-distributed ground-truth data in point format with spatial coordinates and so on. There are like 1200 data points.
- Explanatory variables: a bunch of indirect indicators (topography, landforms, rainfall, geology, etc). These are raster layers. I simply grab the pixel value of each one that corresponds to the location of the wells in the target dataset.

I have managed to develop and train a regression tree in Spyder which predicts groundwater occurrence with reasonable accuracy. Now I'd like to use turn the results into a groundwater occurrence map in a GIS environment (QGIS, to be specific).

If regression trees produced "coefficients" I could simply multiply them by each pixel value in each explanatory variable layer to obtain a prediction for each pixel, and with that develop the map. However, I understand this is not the case because DTs use if/else logic instead of coefficients.

So I'm stuck at this point. Since the model works I feel I'm kinda close, but I wouldn't have a clue as to how to proceed.

So how would you guys go about this?

Comment: What is your input for the regression tree? Would your algorithm be able to provide coefficients for a given (longitude, latitude) pair for the area of the map that you want to cover?